# As the מזמן, should I say "ברשות אבי מורי" before "סבי מורי" or the other way around?

Tags: bentching, kibbud-av-veim-honoring, zimun

When eating with my parents at my my grandparents' (father's parents) house, if I am asked to be מזמן, should I say “ברשות אבי מורי וסבי מורי„ or “ברושת סבי מורי ואבי מורי„?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Benjy. Hope to see you around !

Comment: Why should this be any different than what we  say when eating at someone else’s house with your father?